# Apache add "?" at the end

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I want to rewrite `domain/login` to `domain/login?`

When I try `RewriteRule ^/login https://%{SERVER_NAME}/login?` I get too many redirects.

When I try `RewriteRule ^/login/ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/login?` nothing changes.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why? The `?` is a special character in this context... it delimits the query string, so what you appear to be trying to do (ie. create an essentially _empty_ query string) really does not make much sense without additional context. Is the trailing `?` intended to be part of the URL-path? In which case it would need to be URL-encoded. But do you really want to "rewrite" the request (as tagged `url-rewriting`)? That also doesn't make much sense in this context and is unlikely to work since `/login?` is unlikely to be a valid end-point and requires further rewriting.

Comment: Please clarify in what context you are adding these directives? From the syntax, it looks like you are adding these directly in the `<VirtualHost>` (or _server_) container?